What is wrong with the way I concatenate paths in Emacs elisp
I have a .dir-locals.el file in my project in which I am configuring my project for debugging using dap-debug in Emacs with debugpy.
I have this variant of the .dir-locals.el file that works just fine:
((nil . ((eval . (progn
                   (setq-local my-local-root (projectile-project-root))
                   (setq-local my-local-path (expand-file-name "linux-application/my_app" my-local-root))
                   (message "Project root is: %s" my-local-root)
                   (message "Concatenated path: %s" my-local-path)))
         (dap-debug-template-configurations
          . (("Docker Pytest Debug"
              :type "python"
              :request "attach"
              :hostName "localhost"
              :port 5678
              :name "Docker Pytest Debug"
              :pathMappings ((
                              ( :localRoot .  "/home/my_user/projects/our-gateway/linux-application/my_app")
                              ( :remoteRoot . "/usr/src/app/linux-application/my_app")
                              ))))))))

Now, to make things a bit more general, I would like to replace:
 ( :localRoot .  "/home/my_user/projects/our-gateway/linux-application/my_app")

With something like this:
( :localRoot . my-local-path)

but this does not work. When doing the change the debugger do not find the source code.
This makes me believe the path "my-local-path" is not the same as the string in my working variant. When I look at the print of the variable "my-local-path" in Emacs messages buffer it looks like it is the same though. I have also checked that they both are strings. The file .dir-local.el is in the folder /home/my_user/projects/our-gateway.
I have also tried to do the concatenation with "concat", but that generates the same issue.

dap-debug-template-configurations is outside the eval so of course it doesn't have access to the local variables you declared within it.

Thanks tripleee, you were correct. Here is my working file:
((nil . ((eval . (progn
               (setq-local my-local-root (projectile-project-root))
               (setq-local my-local-path (expand-file-name "linux-application/my_app" my-local-root))
               (message "Project root is: %s" my-local-root)
               (message "Concatenated path: %s" my-local-path)
               (setq dap-debug-template-configurations
                     `(("Docker Pytest Debug"
                        :type "python"
                        :request "attach"
                        :hostName "localhost"
                        :port 5678
                        :name "Docker Pytest Debug"
                        :pathMappings (((:localRoot . ,my-local-path)
                                        (:remoteRoot . "/usr/src/app/linux-application/my_app")))))))))))

So, the error was: "dap-debug-template-configurations is outside the eval so of course it doesn't have access to the local variables you declared within it".
Some comments on the piece of code (I am not that good at elisp, so pleas correct me if I am wrong):

"Docker Pytest Debug" is the name of the template you will see when you start the debugging in Emacs with M x dap-debug.
"attach" tells Emacs that it should attach to a remote debug session.
"port" is the port at which the debugger is listening for Emacs.
"LocalRoot" is the folder where the source code is located on the host running Emacs.
"remoteRoot" is the source code folder within the Docker container where, in my case, debugpy is running.


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

I am not very good at elisp and used chatGPT to get to the above code in the first place, but I will edit my answer with what I know.

I have no insights into "dap-debug", but if dap-debug-template-configurations is not an automatically-buffer-local variable, then you very likely want setq-local rather than setq.

I guess you are right. Thanks!
